# GAE/Flask [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

As the title suggests, I am seeing this error when my flask app tries to run.

I am hosting the application locally using dev_appserver.

The error occurs when I visit the site and it tries to run the app. It appears that GAE is trying and failing to bind a socket for some reason.

I suspect that this may have something to do with OAuth2. Maybe it requires an SSL connection?

I don't even know where to begin solving this as none of the other posts about this are experiencing the same variation of the issue.

**Edit:** Here's a screenshot of the console confirming that the GAE server launches successfully on a different port; still doesn't resolve it

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
      handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
      handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
      obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "C:\Users\XXX\PycharmProjects\ad-assignment\main.py", line 51, in <module>
      app.run()
  File "C:\Users\XXX\PycharmProjects\ad-assignment\lib\flask\app.py", line 843, in run
      run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\PycharmProjects\ad-assignment\lib\werkzeug\serving.py", line 694, in run_simple
      inner()
  File "C:\Users\XXX\PycharmProjects\ad-assignment\lib\werkzeug\serving.py", line 656, in inner
      fd=fd)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\PycharmProjects\ad-assignment\lib\werkzeug\serving.py", line 550, in make_server
      passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\PycharmProjects\ad-assignment\lib\werkzeug\serving.py", line 464, in __init__
      HTTPServer.__init__(self, (host, int(port)), handler)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\SocketServer.py", line 417, in __init__
      self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
      SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\SocketServer.py", line 431, in server_bind
      self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\dist27\socket.py", line 222, in meth
      return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\remote_socket\_remote_socket.py", line 676, in bind
      raise _SystemExceptionFromAppError(e)
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied
INFO     2016-12-16 21:41:51,631 module.py:788] default: "GET /oauth2callback?code=x/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Code (as seen in Google's [OAuth2 usage guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)):

```
import flask


app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    ...


@app.route('/oauth2callback')
def oauth2callback():
    ...


if __name__ == 'main':
    import uuid
    app.secret_key = str(uuid.uuid4())
    app.debug = False
    app.run()
```

Comment: R u trying to run this in your local machine ?

Comment: Did you try a different port? The port might be in use or under 1024 without root.

Comment: Yes I am running it locally. I am not setting the port anywhere as I was just following the guide. The application is hosted by GAE dev_appserver and defaults to using port 8080

Comment: Okey, it might be possible GAE try to run on port which is already used by some other servevice, please configure port in config as @kichik mention in comment. I generally use `9999` for safe side.

Comment: I have used port 8080 successfully before, though. It was working with webapp2 framework earlier but I have since switched to flask.

Comment: Can you please try `8888` ?

Comment: I should mention that the GAE dev_appserver runs fine. It's just when I visit the index page and it executes the `flask.run()`. I've also changed to port 9999 as you've requested with the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a [tutorial that walks you through adding Firebase Authentication to your Python app running with Flask](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/authenticating-users-firebase-appengine). Firebase Authentication is the preferred identity toolkit now. You can of course still use a pure OAuth2 flow, but Firebase Auth also provides multi-provider authentication if that's something you were considering adding to your app anyways. If you just want to dive into the sample's code its [here on GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/firebase/firenotes).

If you just want to stick with straight OAuth, you might want to look at your Flask code itself. [Getting flask to run is pretty easy on App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/getting-started/python-standard-env). My guess is that you're calling some code that you don't need to (`flask.run()`) or you aren't [importing your library properly](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/getting-started/python-standard-env#setting_up_libraries_to_enable_development) (see `appengine_config.py`).

Comment: The Firebase solution looks like the direction I'll be eventually going in so I'll mark this as the answer. Very helpful, thanks!